# Looking for series about young man escaping earth authorities only to find intelligent alien ship on a crater of the moon

Tags: story-identification, spaceship, sentience

I am looking for a book series I read about a young man finishing up high school. He had abilities to know when he was being observed by people or electronics and that got him in trouble. He escapes Earth and ends up on a crater on the moon and finds an ancient spacecraft.

It ultimately turns out to be a intelligent ship that is left over from a proscribed race with forbidden technologies.